# Creating custom aggregations dynamically to use with Pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, python-3.7

I'm trying to dynamically create a dictionary of lambda functions to pass into agg() function in Pandas and count the number of "anomalies".

```
    def prepareAggDict(defDict):
       aggdict={}  

       # iterate over features with upper limit threshold 
       for feature_a, threshold_a in defDict.items():
           aggdict[feature_a] = lambda x: (x >= threshold_a).sum()

       return(aggdict)
```

and I wish to pass different field names with different thresholds, to aggregate by:

```
aggdict = prepareAggDict({"column_a":3500, "column_b":8200})   
dailyAgg = df.groupby([id_col,Date_col]).agg(aggdict)
```

But for some reason, the aggregation is only applying the 2nd item of column_b, and not applying the first one on column_a.
I tried to separate them into different lambdas inside the prepareAggDict function it does work well. Unfortunately, I have to create about 7 different thresholds for different columns and I'd like to create it by passing multiple columns names and their thresholds into a single method that will generate a dictionary of custom aggregation functions to pass to a groupby with agg()

for example:

```
data = {
    "id_col":["A","A","B","B","B"],
    "column_a":[500,4500,8100,300,11500],
    "column_b":[800,22340,7554,300,900]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

aggdict = prepareAggDict({"column_a":3500, "column_b":8200})   
dailyAgg = df.groupby(["id_col"]).agg(aggdict)
```

will produce:
[image: unexpected output!]

I would expect for column_a in group A to have the value of 1 and for B the value of 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lambda function for match by `dict` in `dict.get`, if no match is returned missing value:

```
aggdict = {"column_a":3500, "column_b":8200}
dailyAgg = df.groupby(["id_col"]).agg(lambda x: (x >= aggdict.get(x.name, np.nan)).sum())
print (dailyAgg)
        column_a  column_b
id_col                    
A              1         1
B              2         0
```

EDIT: I think in your solution is not passed `x` for groups values, here is possible solution with [nested functions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51853595/2901002):

```
def prepareAggDict(p):
    def ipf(x):
        return (x >= p).sum()
    return ipf 

    
data = {
    "id_col":["A","A","B","B","B"],
    "column_a":[500,4500,8100,300,11500],
    "column_b":[800,22340,7554,300,900]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

d = {"column_a":3500, "column_b":8200}
aggdict = {k: prepareAggDict(v) for k, v in d.items()}

#return same like
#aggdict = {"column_a":prepareAggDict(3500), "column_b":prepareAggDict(8200)} 

dailyAgg = df.groupby(["id_col"]).agg(aggdict)
print (dailyAgg)
        column_a  column_b
id_col                    
A              1         1
B              2         0
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael it sure works, but any thoughts on how to keep the use of the prepareAggDict ? I simplified the scenario here and I would prefer to keep it.

Comment: Thanks @jezrael it works great. much appreciated.